# building Detox failed during yarn install

Tags: yarnpkg, detox

when i do yarn install i am getting this error:

```
[12/31] ⠈ detox
error /Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/postinstall.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox
Output:
/Users/mluu/Library/Detox/ios/10dbe0f0b761264d99edb06a7f9b999416aad111 was found, but could not find Detox.framework inside it. This means that the Detox framework build process was interrupted.
         deleting /Users/mluu/Library/Detox/ios/10dbe0f0b761264d99edb06a7f9b999416aad111 and trying to rebuild.
Extracting Detox sources...
Building Detox.framework from /Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox/ios_src...
child_process.js:637
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: /Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox/scripts/build_framework.ios.sh
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox/scripts/postinstall.js:2:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
```

why is my detox failing to build? i tried deleting my detox folder like it suggested but it still fail to build.

went into /Users/mluu/Library/Detox/ios/10dbe0f0b761264d99edb06a7f9b999416aad111/detox_ios.log and found this:

```
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    cd /Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox/ios_src
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/mluu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/Users/mluu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/Users/mluu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/Users/mluu/.rvm/bin:/Users/mluu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mluu/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/mluu/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/mluu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/mluu/Library/Android/sdk/emulator"
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk
    export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name Detox -O -whole-module-optimization -enforce-exclusivity=checked @/Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swoop-bjgdbvjbcvywzdbnzaexyenmqpew/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/BetaDebug-iphoneos/React.build/Objects-normal/arm64/React.SwiftFileList -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -target arm64-apple-ios11.3 -g -module-cache-path /Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -profile-coverage-mapping -profile-generate -swift-version 4.2 -I /Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -I /Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox/ios_src/Detox -F /Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -c -num-threads 16 /Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox/ios_src/Detox/DetoxUserActivityDispatcher.swift /Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox/ios_src/Detox/DetoxUserNotificationDispatcher.swift -output-file-map /Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Detox-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Detox.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/Detox-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/Detox-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/Detox-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/Detox-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/include -Xcc -IEarlGrey/fishhook -Xcc -I/Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/DerivedSources -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Detox-Swift.h -import-underlying-module -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Detox-bpzzkihbqsknjafrnjvkjdiarlnq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Detox.build/Release-iphoneos/Detox.build/unextended-module-overlay.yaml -working-directory /Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox/ios_src
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox/ios_src/@/Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swoop-bjgdbvjbcvywzdbnzaexyenmqpew/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/BetaDebug-iphoneos/React.build/Objects-normal/arm64/React.SwiftFileList'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(1 failure)
```

why is it looking for arm64/React.SwiftFileList? how do i generate this? i tried going into xcode and running my app in on an actual iphone 7 to get it to generate the arm64 version but nothing is generated when i looked back into that folder. something else must be wrong?

Comment: Something in your environment seems broken. When building Detox, there should be no React in there whatsoever, but in your case it's looking for `/Users/mluu/Developer/mobile2/node_modules/detox/ios_src/@/Users/mluu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swoop-bjgdbvjbcvywzdbnzaexyenmqpew/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/BetaDebug-iphoneos/React.build/Objects-normal/arm64/React.SwiftFileList`

Answer (score 3):

Method one: to make `npm i` successful, just disable detox if you don't need detox for a moment of npm,

To disable detox run this on project terminal `export DETOX_DISABLE_POSTINSTALL=1` and rerun `npm i`.

Method two: degrade your x-code version to 12.4. It also works for me